# How to create advanced ggplot stratifying by a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a data frame in R with several different columns, such as this

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(
    "order" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C","C","D"), 
    "family" = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "B_3", "C_1","C_2","D_1"), 
    "counts"=c(10,23,51,21,89,32,58,9,67)
)
a
```

I want to make a bar plot of the counts for each family within in order. I know that sounds confusing, but order A has families A_1, A_2 and A_3, order B has families B_1, B_2, B_3 and so on... Each of these families within an order has a specific count, which is the "counts" column. I have tried this simple command:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=family, y=counts)) + geom_bar()
```

but this does not stratify by order and present each family within and order. How would I achieve this stratification and have all families within orders displayed on the same plot page in R?

Comment: I don't understand what you want your plot to look like. What do you want on the `x` axis? Just the values "A","B","C","D"? Then `ggplot(a, aes(x=order, y=counts)) + geom_boxplot()` would work. Otherwise I'm not sure how you want to make box plots from single count values. A single number doesn't have a distribution.

Comment: @MrFlick That is my mistake I wasn't thinking. How would I do simple barplots of the counts for family by order? I edited the question to reflect.

Comment: Well, since you are specifying by `y`, then do you just want `ggplot(a, aes(x=family, y=counts)) + geom_col()`? That seems to work fine with your test data.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes that works for family by counts. But I want to further stratify those bars into graphs by order. So A_1, A_2, A_3 go into an A "order" plot. B_1, B_2, B_3 go into the B "order" plot and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: By "stratify" do you mean you want facets? Maybe `ggplot(a, aes(x=family, y=counts)) + geom_col() + facet_grid(cols=vars(order), space="free_x", scales="free_x")`?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks that worked. One more question, how do I flip the bars horizontal and allow enough space for longer "family "names to be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some terms.  By "stratify", the term you're looking for is called "grouping": you want to display one column with number of counts per `a$family` and *group* those columns by `a$order`.  Luckily, this seeming "advanced" plot is actually pretty easy to create once you understand a bit about the terminology and usage in `ggplot2`.  I'll walk you through the process so it is clearly understandable.

First, the basic plot.  You're using `geom_bar()`, but you should be using `geom_col()` here.  You can [read about the reason why in the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html), but it is sufficient to say that if you are only specifying an x aesthetic, you use `geom_bar()`.  If you are specifying x and y aesthetics, you use `geom_col()`.

For the *grouping* part, you have basically two options:  (1) use grouping and dodging, or (2) use faceting.  Both work fine, and honestly it depends on what you want the output to look like.  I'll show both.

### Grouping and Dodging

Grouping is pretty clear.  "Dodging" means that `ggplot` takes your groups and separates them by modifying how they are shown along your x axis.  The approach is to use `a$order` as your x axis, and `a$family` for grouping.  If we just plot this, you get the plot below:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=order, y=counts)) + geom_col(color='black', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

I've added an `alpha=` value and colored the outline of the bars black so that we can see what's going on here:  all the bars for `a$family` are plotting on top of one another, since multiple `a$family` bars share the same `a$order` value.  Your bars are therefore "grouped", but they are not separated out so we can see them.  Doing this is what is known as "dodging": separating placement of geoms that share the same x value to avoid overplotting.  We handle that placement using `position=`.  The problem is that `ggplot2` still needs to be told on what column you want to perform the groups.  For that, you need the `group=` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=order, y=counts, group=family)) +
  geom_col(
    position='dodge',
    color='black', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Looks great, but you need to control a few things here.  We need some way to identify the bars and also need to control the relative widths of each bar... we would like them to be the same size.  That bar to the right is wider than all the rest and is ugly.

To fix the bar widths, you can use `position=position_dodge2(preserve='single')`.  Using `position_dodge2()` is important here, because the related `position_dodge()` would work, but not center along each x axis position.

To add labels, I'll use `geom_text()`.  Note a few things we do though, which is to "nudge" the values up a bit by adding some value to the `y=` aesthetic.  I also need to use the same `position=` argument we used for the bars to apply to the text so that it dodges the same amount.

```
p <- ggplot(a, aes(x=order, y=counts, group=family)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(width=0.8, preserve='single'), color='black', alpha=0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label=family, y=counts+3), position=position_dodge2(width=0.8, preserve='single'))
p
```

[image]

By the way, another good way to identify the families would be to use a different `fill=` aesthetic applied to `a$family`.  I'm not going to show you that here though, since I would recommend doing a few other things with your data first (not for this question!).
Finally, we can make your vertical bars horizontal by adding `coord_flip()` to our plot (which switches the axes):

```
p + coord_flip()
```

[image]

### Faceting

The other way to group is to use facets.  In this case, you plot `a$family` as the x axis and then "separate" your groups using `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`.  Here, I'll use `facet_grid()`.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=family, y=counts)) +
  geom_col(color='black', alpha=0.2) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(order ~ ., scales = 'free', space='free')
```

[image]

We don't need any labeling mechanism here, but I do like to use `facet_grid` here for the specific reason that we can use the `space=` argument--which is not present in `facet_wrap()`.  Without this argument, the facets would be made equal size, and the result is pretty similar to what we had in Grouping and Dodging before using `position_dodge2(preserve='single')`.  The `scales=` argument is needed because otherwise you will have blanks in every facet for every `a$family` - even if nothing exists.

If you want to mess with placement of the facet labels, you use `switch=` inside `facet_grid()` (check the documentation for how).  To change the look of those labels, you use `theme()` elements `strip.*`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Is there any way to make the bars different colors by facet. So make "A" bars all blue, "B" bars all green,etc.?

Comment: Just add `fill=order` within `aes()`.  You can add it in the `ggplot()` function or within `geom_col()`.

Comment: @r2evans got it.